# In Orphan Black, how much do we know about Siobhan Sadler's backstory/activities with the Birdwatchers?

Tags: orphan-black

In *Orphan Black*, when she was younger, Siobhan belonged to/worked with some group called the Birdwatchers, who seem to be some kind of sometimes-violent leftist guerrilla group. They may also be the ones who gave Siobhan the experience and resources to take her adopted children, go off the grid and vanish, and resettle in Canada. Do we know anything else about Siobhan’s shady past, whether her group was the Birdwatchers, what her agenda was?